# Limesurvey concatenating string and token attribute in IF statement

Tags: javascript, php, limesurvey

I would like toa achieve this

```
{if(TOKEN:ATTRIBUTE_11=="CIB", "Note: this team is associated with the following ID(s): TOKEN:ATTRIBUTE_5,"")}
```

But something is wrong here. I've tried `{}` for `TOKEN:ATTRIBUTE_5` and `.` operator.

Comment: Best is to read the manual https://manual.limesurvey.org/Expression_Manager#Operators before asking question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{if(TOKEN:ATTRIBUTE_11=="CIB", join("Note: this team is associated with the following ID(s): ", TOKEN:ATTRIBUTE_5),"")}
```